# Installing pagekite/owncloud remote access on Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: installation, command-line, server

Does anyone know the commands to install pagekite on Ubuntu server 12.04. I already have the ssh and lamp dependencies installed. I am trying to access my owncloud server from anywhere. If anyone has any way of making it so I can access the owncloud browser from anywhere please let me know. @Pieter.

Comment: May I ask why you want to install Pagekite although you have already setup an Ubuntu server? Because of a dynamic IP address?

Comment: Yes I have a dynamic IP address, although my external IP has not changed in at least 2 years. I don't really know what I am doing, I just read about pagekite and it seemed like it would take care of the situation. If you know how to access owncloud remotely please let me know. I think I have to forward the port, although not sure how to find out which one I need to forward. And I don't know any commands to forward my internal ports, I only know how to forward through my router. From what I've read there are a few other steps too but I am unclear what they are.

Answer (score 0):

actually I wrote up a tutorial on setting up owncloud a while ago which also deals with port forwarding. It's [here](http://matveen.blogspot.nl/2013/04/set-up-owncloud-server-at-home.html).

Gd luck.